# Casting object from Drop Down Into Nullable type

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following drop down in my aspx:

```
<aspx:DropDownList
ID="ddl1"
runat="server"/>
```

In the code-behind (C#), I want to retrieve the value from the DropDownList.

I populated my dropdown as such:

```
ddl1.DataSource = LocationOfData;
ddl1.DataBind();
```

LocationOfData returns of type CustomType. EDIT: CustomType is an enum.

I want to be able to accomplish the following:

```
CustomType? myvar = ddl1.Text
```

In other words, create a nullable variable using my CustomType and set it equal to the variable from the drop down. But the type that I can only retrieve Text (String) from ddl1.

Comment: what is the definition of CustomType? ?

Comment: After further examining my problem, I realized that CustomType is an enum of values.

Comment: string is a reference type you only need to create a nullable variable for value types.

Comment: If CustomType is defined as 

    public enum CustomType
    {
        etc....
    }

Than it should be possible to make a nullable type CustomType?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `CustomType` is an Enum you first have to parse your `ddl1.Text` to an Enum and then cast it to a Nullable type:

```
CustomType? myvar = (CustomType?) Enum.Parse(typeof(CustomType), ddl1.Text, true)
```

Answer (score 0):

If `CustomType` is an `enum`, instead of binding the name of the enum, I would set the values of your drop down list when you bind to the `byte` value of the enum. Then when you are attempting to cast to `CustomType`, you can just do:

```
CustomType myvar = (CustomType)byte.Parse(ddl1.Text);
```

Do a check first to create a nullable type. I don't know what your criteria is, but:

```
CustomType? myvar;
if(/*Criteria*/)
{
    myvar = (CustomType)byte.Parse(ddl1.Text);
}
else
{
    myvar = null;
}
```